# Add Image in Kotlin Multiplatform

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

I can't add image in jetpack compose

```
fun FolderView(
    text: String,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .clickable { onClick() }) {
        Row {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(res = "drawable-nodpi/folder_view"),
                contentDescription = null
            )
            Text(text = text)
        }
    }
}
```

![Community Verified icon](data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAQAAAAngNWGAAABDUlEQVR4AYXRgUZDYRjH4TegFTKgpEqiFJgoWAoMEQGBgBboChaaAKxLKAhAhQqAdAmpBIQolkCFqp2nITvNKXuA7+/Hhzey5OWjE4Nq3rzY1f9/NGHPB549492+8Ww060iCS2XdctZdI3GsECmb+HJoIX6x6EgDm+lURTH+YB7V9nAqE5WNme4YKuOiY6iMe6PaQxUUIuTbswgFVNJwA8sO3Bn6yR6bWZMSNtJwDtuWfHpQxaPx9C9zadil7jrCigbq6UXceNIVKTWUIqypm2ytJdTiNyNeXclF6GttOVfeDEc7qzjR23r3OMFqZKng1kw0mXGLrfibHTScOZWgGv9TdC6ROFeMTgwYiIxvJzMRWQbeGZUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=)[image]

I've already tried using R.Drawable, but it doesn't work... I'm migrating to Multiplatform now

![Community Verified icon](data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAQAAAAngNWGAAABDUlEQVR4AYXRgUZDYRjH4TegFTKgpEqiFJgoWAoMEQGBgBboChaaAKxLKAhAhQqAdAmpBIQolkCFqp2nITvNKXuA7+/Hhzey5OWjE4Nq3rzY1f9/NGHPB549492+8Ww060iCS2XdctZdI3GsECmb+HJoIX6x6EgDm+lURTH+YB7V9nAqE5WNme4YKuOiY6iMe6PaQxUUIuTbswgFVNJwA8sO3Bn6yR6bWZMSNtJwDtuWfHpQxaPx9C9zadil7jrCigbq6UXceNIVKTWUIqypm2ytJdTiNyNeXclF6GttOVfeDEc7qzjR23r3OMFqZKng1kw0mXGLrfibHTScOZWgGv9TdC6ROFeMTgwYiIxvJzMRWQbeGZUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=)

Comment: `painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.folder_view)`